Unable to access details page for vehicle crash entitlement (SafetyKit)
I am part of a team working to incorporate vehicle crash detection using SafetyKit.
However, I am unable to know more details about this entitlement since the details page (https://developer.apple.com/contact/request/vehicular-crash-events/) is showing an unauthorised message saying “You’re account can’t access this page”. All the latest licenses have been reviewed and agreed to. Please let me know what can be done to access this link and know the details of this entitlement.
Unauthorized error page

Click on "visit your account". It will probably show that your organisation does need to agree to a new license.
